# How to let users read p7m files online

Tags: php, digital-signature

i'm running a php/mysql based website.
I already let my users upload p7m files (most of them are pdf digital signed).
Is there a solution to let users watch them on site (online) directly without download them? Like google does with pdf, or rtf files?

Thank you

S.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If these files are just MIME blobs, then extract the main part and display it (for text/plain or /html content). Any existing file signature has no impact for displaying.

Regarding the embeddable PDF viewing, this is probably a sufficient option:
http://googlesystem.blogspot.com/2009/09/embeddable-google-document-viewer.html